# PHP GEOPlugin get info by country code?

Tags: php, request, location

I'm using http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php to get info about visitors country and country code, is there a way to get info about country by requesting something like:
www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?country=rus or something?
I hope u understand what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make sense. The API is for getting country of the visitor by looking up their IP. Country information does not seem to be the business that the API is into.

Potentially you can achieve this by maintaining a list of IPs per country and firing that API against the IP of the country in which you are interested.